# Edit Software Distribution Path in Existing GPO

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012, deployment

There is an existing GPO to deploy a software package, the path is no longer valid.  I need to either edit the UNC path or create a new Package.  I would prefer to edit existing package/modification, or create a new modification in the existing package.  Neither is an option, see screen shot with Add & Remove buttons greyed out.  I have confirmed my user has Full permisions on this GPO object.

The remove package option states "Allow users to continue to use the software, but prevent further installations."  I am unclear if this would apply only to this package?

Besides using DFS to make this easier going forward what is the best practice for making this type of change?  My research only found this to make an edit http://www.frickelsoft.net/blog/?p=78

DC:  Server 2012
AD Functional Level:  Windows Server 2003

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifications and transforms are [applied at the time of assignment or publication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778924%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Hence, they can only be added when the GPO software package is created. This is a Group Policy limitation.

So, in this case, you should create a new package using the `Advanced` option, identifying the old  package in the `Upgrade` tab and adding the appropriate mst(s) in the `Modifications` tab. This should upgrade the existing installations on your network.

Comment: Thanks, we came to same conclusion re. start over w/ Advanced option but have not used the Upgrade feature, will definitely look into that now.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using ADSI Edit.

1. Open GPEdit and locate the GPO containing the package with the MSI assignment you would like to change the path of. In the right panel click Details tab and note GPO's Unique ID (GUID).

   --- OR ---

   In the GPO Editor, go to Computer Configuration/User Configuration, Policies, Software Settings, Software Installation. Double click on any MSI deployed. Click the Deployment tab, then click the Advanced button. GPO's Unique ID is the GUID in the Script Name location value right after "\Policies".
2. Open the ADSI editor. On the left panel with tree, connect to your domain and navigate to the CN=System, CN=Policies, CN=<GPO's Unique ID>, CN=Machine, CN=Class Store, CN=Packages.
3. Right click on the Package Object and select Properties. Navigate to the Optional property `msiFileList`. This property contains the UNC path of the location of the MSI Installer file. Edit this value to represent the new UNC path.

NOTE: It is possible to have multiple UNC paths defined for a Package Object, starting with 0:, then 1: and so on. If you are changing the UNC path, type in the new UNC path, prefixed with 0: and click the Add button. Select the old UNC path and click the Remove button.

BONUS: You can use URL or local path to MSI instead of UNC. The documentation explicitly advertises UNC, since the path must reliably resolve to the MSI file on every computer GPO applies.

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/troubleshoot/windows-server/group-policy/change-msi-file-location-in-software-deployment-gpo